# Getting IMediaExtension to work with MediaComposition

Tags: directx, directx-11, windows-phone-8.1, ms-media-foundation, win-universal-app

I was attempting to use [Windows Phone Media Extensions](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Media-extensions-sample-7b466096) sample with MediaComposition:

I'm trying to run InvertTransform from the sample by adding it to MediaComposition on Windows Phone 8:

```
var composition = new MediaComposition();
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///videos/test.mp4"));
var clip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(file);
clip.VideoEffectDefinitions.Add(new VideoEffectDefinition("InvertTransform.InvertEffect"));
composition.Clips.Add(clip);
```

This fails, probably because video subtype is MFVideoFormat_NV12 while effect is handling only MFVideoFormat_ARGB32.

How can invert transform be used in this scenario? Does it have to be changed to support MFVideoFormat_NV12 and how best to accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: Down-voting this without a comment is stupidity. This is a legit question. The guy who down-voted prob. doesn't even know MediaComposition. That's what I would guess. People are down-vote happy these days. Come on!

Answer (score 0):

After doing lot of tests, only way to do this is to handle NV12 format, and convert to and back from RGB, if needed.